# How to pop back to a view in a different navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, unwind-segue

I want to create the following user flow in my Swift application:

1. User clicks a button
2. A modal view pops over with a choice. The user selects a choice.
3. A second view appears with another choice (using a "show" transition, so the user can press **< Back** to alter choice #1). The user selects the second choice.
4. The second modal view segues back to the original view (which has the button).

To do this, I created the following structure:

```
--> NC1 --> VC1 --modal-> NC2 --> VC2 --show-> VC3    (NC = UINavigationController,
             ^                                  |      VC = UIViewController)
             |                                  |
             ----Segue I'm trying to achieve-----
```

I've tried to pop all the way back to VC1 by passing a reference to VC1 all the way through to VC3, then calling the following code in VC3:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Perform Segue
    print("Trying to segue")
    rootController!.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

where `rootController` is the reference to VC1. Unfortunately the segue doesn't occur; the second modal view stays on the screen, but I get the "Trying to segue" message printed.

Am I trying to implement this user flow the right way? If so, any suggestions why I can't pop to a root view in another navigation controller?

Comment: in your navigation controller there is a property called viewControllers that contain all the controllers in you have navigated, remove those that you want  to skip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, you can do this using an unwind segue.

In VC1 implement an `@IBAction` method, which takes a `UIStoryboardSegue` as parameter:

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

Then from the Prototype cell of VC3 control-drag to the Exit icon of the view controller, select `Selection Segue: unwindToVC1:` and you are good to go.

[image]

You can achieve a similar result using code also.
Implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in VC3 like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    navigationController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor, I used `dismissViewControllerAnimated` as you suggested in VC3 and it did the job.