# popping to root view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have an alert whose OK button should pop to the root view controller.

Here's the structure of what I'm working with:

[tab view controller] -> [navigation controller] -> **[view controller]** -> *[view controller]* -> [navigation controller] -> [view controller] -> [alert]

I would like the OK button on the alert take me to the view controller I've bolded above. When I do the code below, I go back to the view controller I've italicized above, which isn't quite what I want. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: OK, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        _ = self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
}))
```

I have also tried using the special method for popping to the root view controller, but this has not worked, sadly.

Comment: how do you used this once `[view controller] -> [view controller] `, the segue type as PUSH or present

Comment: In my storyboard, I use Push

Comment: which view Controller is it opening. If you can tell me which ViewController opens from your viewHierarchy graph then I can help you out

Comment: it opens the one in italics (slanted letters), after the bold one

Comment: The ViewController is the ViewController in which your naviagtion controller is present.

Comment: Get a reference to the first navigationController and call the popToRootViewController for that NavigationController

Comment: `UIAlertAction` blocks already execute on the main thread. You shouldn't need the GCD in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `UINavigationViewController` class has a method `func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]?` ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller))

You can just call this method on the fist navigation view controller. (Note: Therefore you need to have a reference to this navigation view controller or delegates to call this method)

If you use a Storyboard you can use a segue to unwind to the correct view controller. Therefore see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681691/how-to-pop-back-to-a-view-in-a-different-navigation-controller?rq=1).

Comment: I have tried using popToRootViewController, but I've had some issues. Based on your answer, it might be because I am calling it on the later navigationViewController. How do I access the first navigation view controller?

Comment: (how do I access it from the very last view controller, that is)

Comment: Yes, you need to call it on the first navigation view controller. And yes, therefore you need to keep a reference. Are you using a Storyboard? Than segues might help you (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681691/how-to-pop-back-to-a-view-in-a-different-navigation-controller?rq=1)) Otherwise either create delegates  along the way or store it somewhere you can access (maybe in the later navigation view controller if you have a subclass?) - Sorry not easy to answer without knowing more of your code :)

Comment: I am using a storyboard. I just checked out that link, and I see that it suggests unwinding. I actually tried that already and had the same problem!  I did so using this tutorial (https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/), which has successfully worked for me in the past. Is there anything else that I can tell you about my code that might help?

Comment: What exactly is the problem when using the unwind segue?

Comment: Oh, IT JUST STARTED WORKING!! I checked over my work and realized I put my IBAction unwind function in the wrong file on accident! It works now, at long last! Thanks for the help @Nef10

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I might access my tabBarController from my very last view controller? I ask because there are two possible view controllers I'd want to unwind to, depending on which tab I'm on. self.tabBarController is nil in that last view controller.

Comment: Try the first line of code in Bilals answer - it is not the best way (IMHO) but should work. Cleaner would still be creating appropriate delegates or have references at the right positions

Comment: I actually did try his/her first line, and it didn't work! Maybe I'll just go the delegate route. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate the particular index of navigate stack.
E.g:- First get the count of view controllers present in navigation stack. Pop to particular index. In you case may be its `index` is 0:

```
let arr_controller:[UIViewController] = (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)!
_ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(arr_controller[0], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let tabVc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
tabVc?.selectedViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```